# Better extensible arrows

Tags: amsmath, arrows

Using `amsmath` and `extarrows` packages, we have many extensible arrows. But these arrows look ugly, since some parts in an arrow are boldfaced.

[image]

Are there any better-looking extensible arrows?

Comment: They are not really bold, just overlapping slightly which affects the anti-aliasing in low resolution. They should print OK. tikz or pstricks or xypick can all _draw_ arrows instead of using repeated character segments, which may suit you better

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The overlapping makes arrows look ugly when reading document in computer. Why overlapping is necessary in these extensible arrows? I notice that in `xypic`, long arrows look better than these.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle But how to use an arrow drawn by `tikz` or `xypic` as an operater inside a math formula? It seems not easy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a substitute for `\xrightarrow` made with Xy-pic

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}

\newlength{\xywd}
\newcommand{\xyrightarrow}[2][]{%
  \sbox{0}{$\scriptstyle#1$}%
  \xywd=\wd0
  \sbox{0}{$\scriptstyle#2$}%
  \ifdim\wd0>\xywd \xywd=\wd0 \fi
  \xymatrix@C\dimexpr\xywd+1em\relax{{}\ar[r]^{#2}_{#1}&{}}%
}

\begin{document}
\[
X \xyrightarrow[r_1-r_2]{r_2-r_1} Y
\]
\[
X \xyrightarrow[r_1-r_2+r_3]{r_2-r_1} Y
\]
\[
X \xyrightarrow{r_2-r_1} Y
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. It seems that you should have `\xywd` instead of `\xywd0` in the code above.

Comment: @PedroSánchezTerraf The `0` doesn't definitely belong there, thanks!