# How to draw a labeled triple arrow (\Rrightarrow)

Tags: amsmath, arrows, labels, amssymb

There exists the ams-symbol `\Rrightarrow` which gives a triple arrow like

[image: triple arrow].

Now I want to endow the arrow with a label, which for example in the case of double arrows works with `\xRightarrow{f}`. But unfortunately the corresponding command for labeled triple arrows `\xRrightarrow` seems not to exist.

I am aware of the `\overset` command, but overset doesn't lengthen the arrow in case the label is longer than the `\xRrightarrow` symbol.

So my question is: What is the simplest way to draw a labeled triple arrow whose length is adjusted to the length of its label?

Comment: in order to extend an arrow, there must be an extender.  for the computer modern fonts, the extender for (horizontal) two-stem arrows is the equals sign.  there wasn't any extender made specifically for three-stem arrows, although i suppose that the `\equiv` symbol could be tried.  the technique should be derivable from the definition of `\Longrightarrow` in `amsmath.sty`, but i haven't got time to try it right now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're lucky: `\equiv` and `\Rrightarrow` can be combined.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\xRrightarrow}[2][]{\ext@arrow 0359\Rrightarrowfill@{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\Rrightarrowfill@}{\arrowfill@\equiv\equiv\Rrightarrow}
\newcommand{\xLleftarrow}[2][]{\ext@arrow 3095\Lleftarrowfill@{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\Lleftarrowfill@}{\arrowfill@\Lleftarrow\equiv\equiv}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$A\xRrightarrow{fghi}B$

$A\xLleftarrow{fghi}B$

\end{document}
```

[image]

One can also add the symmetric version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\xRrightarrow}[2][]{\ext@arrow 0359\Rrightarrowfill@{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\Rrightarrowfill@}{\arrowfill@\equiv\equiv\Rrightarrow}
\newcommand{\xLleftarrow}[2][]{\ext@arrow 3095\Lleftarrowfill@{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\Lleftarrowfill@}{\arrowfill@\Lleftarrow\equiv\equiv}
\newcommand{\xLleftRrightarrow}[2][]{\ext@arrow 3399\LleftRrightarrowfill@{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\LleftRrightarrowfill@}{\arrowfill@\Lleftarrow\equiv\Rrightarrow}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$A\xRrightarrow{fghi}B$

$A\xLleftarrow{fghi}B$

$A\xLleftRrightarrow{fghi}B$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have not undestood the question, then. :-( As usual for me.

Answer (score 3):

Label over `\Rrightarrow` and `\rightrightarrows`. It is possible to use a triple arrows with `TikZ` macro: see this link [Custom arrow shaft in tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230098/custom-arrow-shaft-in-tikz).

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[a \stackrel{\text{label}}{\Rrightarrow}
 f\]
 \[a \stackrel{\text{label}}{\rightrightarrows}
 f\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible also to use `xy` package to have your symbol:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

Let a free text before  \raisebox{.55ex}{\xymatrix@C=3pc{ A \ar@3{->}[r]^{\txt{\tiny Small}} &B}} and after.

\xymatrix { A \ar@3{<-}[r]^{\txt{\tiny Over}} &B}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Explanation of the code*:

1. `\raisebox{.55ex}{....}` to put the triple arrow approximatively to the same line of the text using `graphicx` package.
2. `\xymatrix@C=3pc{ A \ar@3{->}[r]^{\txt{\tiny Small}} &B}` it is the code of 3 line with arrow (right) or option left using `<-` with the over text using `^` or under using `_`. `@C=3pc` give to you the lenght of the arrow.

If you prefer to have a macro I can provide to improved my other answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my [pdfMsym](https://ctan.org/pkg/pdfmsym?lang=en) package for this.

```latex
% The following two lines go in your preamble
\input pdfmsym
\pdfmsymsetscalefactor{10} % Change 10 to the font size you're using

$$ \xvarRrightarrow{over}[under] $$
```

[image: xvarRrightarrow usage]
I added this feature partially because of this question.
Its benefit over using overlapping `\equiv`s is that many PDF viewers don't rasterize that nicely, and the areas which overlap form a "bump" ([there are even some questions regarding that](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136752/better-extensible-arrows)). pdfMsym's arrows tend to rasterize nicer (in my experience), since the extendable part of the arrow is drawn instead of using overlapping symbols.
Though one drawback is that the arrow tip used here is different than the arrow tip of `\Rrightarrow`.

Another alternative would be to just draw this yourself, using any one of the LaTeX packages meant for drawing (eg TikZ), or to use `\pdfliteral`s with PDF graphics code.